# Detecting electron spin

Tags: electrons, quantum-spin

Is this right?When an electron passes tnrough a detector it starts precessing but no matter of the first electrom spin orientation the highest spin magnitude is detected.In that case  I am confused... is the electron precessing or it just gets maximaly aligned with the magnetic field of the detector?